# How to build libHaru and the examples which are included

Tags: bash, compiling, install-from-source, make

I downloaded libHaru from http://libharu.org/. libHaru is a opensource pdf creator. Now in the INSTALL file says I only have to run `./configure && make && make install`. When I run this I get the error `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`. Yes I am in the correct same folder as where I extracted the files, there is however a file called `configure.in` which I guess has something to do with it.

Now next to how I can build libHaru I would like to know how I can build the examples. I only see a file `CMakelist.txt` doesn't each example need a make file on its own?

Comment: there seems to be a package for libharu  `sudo apt-get install libhpdf-2.2.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install CMake and cd to the build directory and command:

```
cmake .
```

If you want to have more control install cmake Gui

Comment: Okay thanks! That did the trick indeed. Can you also clearify how I can build now the examples? Since I only have a `.c` file and no make file?

Comment: I have never used the library. I was just throwing my cmake experience. Have you checked in examples dir and there is no cmake list file? Or may be examples are build into some sort of bin directory?

Comment: on second thought I didn't think it worked :P

Comment: what do you mean?